# Owin Bearer Token With Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

Guys!

I'm looking for a solution for this problem for a couple weeks.

I have to develop a ASP.Net WebAPI solution that uses the Windows Authentication mode and generates a bearer token through Identity/Owin middleware.

The idea of this solution is to communicate with an AngularJS application and authenticate like the most WebAPI does with Identity.

When I try to make an example of the FormBased Authentication, but with the Windows Authentication mode, the WebAPI can recognize the credentials in the controllers, but not in the Bearer Token Generator.

Do anyone had this issue before or know how to fix this?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Not clear to me. Are you building a service that uses Windows authentication to generate a token? Or are you building a service that consumes a token acquired through Windows authentication?

Comment: Actually, I'm building a service that will receive the Windows Authentication  "parameters" (like Username), compare if this user is registered in my database and creates a token for this authenticated user.
Like occurs in this example [link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/), but I would like to have Windows Authentication.

Comment: Why would you generate a token if your user is already authenticated via windows auth?

Comment: My bad, buddy. I was thinking I should generate a token to ensure the user is logged.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Came across your post and think its still relevant as now I'm doing the same thing for an existing Windows Authenticated app, IE trying to add token authentication as a second level of security to prevent Cross Site Request Forgery attacks. Too bad you never got any answers here.